# Expense form workflow rejecting

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, infopath, designer-workflow

I moved over an on prem Sharepoint to O365 and have been having a minor issue with the approval workflow setup.

The workflow triggers and runs through, however even when "Approve" is selected, it rejects the expense report.

In the workflow status page is the last 2 lines read "Approval was completed" and "Updating Form Status"

The emails trigger and get sent out informing the user when the approval is started and again when it is rejected. Any ideas? Screenshots of the workflow section it is hanging/being sent back at below.

[image]

[image]